# Parallel cURL request using PHP multithreading

Tags: php, multithreading, curl

I have a function **callFunctions()** which basically calls various functions, say **api1()**, **api2()**, **api3()**, etc..
These functions make cURL requests to various APIs which return data which I then parse and merge into a globally declared array, say **$finalData**
Earlier i was calling these functions in linear order and each function took their own time to fetch results, parse and merge them into **$finalData**.

```
global $finalData = array();
callFunctions(){
    api1();
    api2();
    ..
    ..
    api10();
}
```

But it takes a lot of time to get the final data due to large number of requests.
So, I tried to call these functions parallely using Multi-threading.

```
class ApiParallelQueries extends Thread {
    public function __construct($i){
        $this->i=$i;
    }
    public function run(){
        selectApis($this->i);
    }
}

function selectApis($i){
    switch($i){
        case 1: api1();break;
        case 2: api2();break;
        ..
        ..
        case 10: api10();break;
    }
}

callFunctions(){
    for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
        $workers[$i] = new ApiParallelQueries($i);
        $workers[$i]->start();
    }

    for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
        $workers[$i]->join();
    }
}
```

But the problem is, I'm not getting the result I was getting from the sequential function calls.
I'm not sure if it has something to do with global variables or not but i'm guessing thats the problem,
could it be some other issue? can we not make cURL requests with multithreading?

**Note:** I also noticed a strange thing while i was trying this, i tried to print timestamps and the time was different when the functions were called using multi-threading.

Comment: Have you ever thought about asynchronous requesting via curl and then a fan-in approach to collect data? It seems that a lot of people are using php threads for curl requests but async http request  is a trillion times better than spawning X threads where each of them is simply performing a blocking request via socket. [Have you checked this out](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)?

Comment: i would've implemented this if it was my own code. But its not, and the people who wrote it created different functions for different requests. I 'm just trying to clean up their mess but i want to avoid re-writing all the code. Isn't there any other, faster way to fix this?

Comment: Well, we're getting into theoretical area now where all we can do is guess. I don't know what your functions do, it's also not clear whether they must be executed one after another in sequence (synchronous) or if it's fine if their result arrives when it arrives (asynchronous). If the final results depends on synchronous function execution then you have no choice but to leave it as is or rewrite the code to be async. If you can work with result coming in when it comes in then it's better to use async curl approach that I linked.